# PHP table not showing even the variable are exaclty the same

Tags: php

let me first show you guys my code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include("selectDB.php");
        myconnection();
        $type="Payment";


        $loan1="201410000account-00002";
        $loan=$_GET['lid'];
        echo $loan;
        $myquery="select time,month,day,year,amount from payment,loan,account where account.transactiontype='".$type."' and account.memberid='" .$_SESSION['memberid']. "' and payment.accountid=account.accountid and payment.loanid=loan.loanid and loan.loanid='".$loan."'";
        $results=mysql_query($myquery);
        echo "<table border='2' align='left'>";
        echo "<tr style='background-color:black;color:white' align='center'><td>Rows</td><td>Transaction Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Time</td><td>Date</td></tr>";
        $counter=0;
        $payment=0;
        while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($results))
        {
                $payment+=$rs['amount'];
                $counter+=1;
                echo"<td align='center'>".$counter."</td>";
                echo"<td align='center'>".$type."</td>";
                echo"<td>".number_format($rs['amount'], 2, '.', ',')."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$rs['time']."</td>";
                echo"<td> ".$rs['month']."/".$rs['day']."/".$rs['year']."</td>";
                echo "<tr>";    

        }
        echo "</table>";    

        $paymentformat=number_format($payment, 2, '.', ',');


        ?>
```

This is what it looks like:  http://s1.postimg.org/m3zo71f8f/Screen_Shot_2014_12_10_at_10_49_54_AM.pngas you can see there is a text there that says:

> 201410000account-00002

because of the code:

```
$loan=$_GET['lid'];
echo $loan;
```

Notice $loan variable is exactly the same this $loan1 because i directly assign the variable of $loan1 to match the contents of $_GET['lid'];

```
$loan1="201410000account-00002";
```

The weird thing is that when i change my query to this:

```
loan.loanid='".$loan1."'";
```

The table shows. I dont get it guys $loan is exaclty the same with $loan1

This is the where $_GET['lid']; comes from:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
            <script>
               $(function(){
                 $('tr').click(function() {
                    selectedTd=$(this).find('td:first-child').text();

                 });
               });
            </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">


function loadXMLDoc()
            {

            var datavars="mid="+<?php echo $mid; ?>;
            var datavars2="lid="+selectedTd;
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("u429").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","displaypayment.php?"+datavars2,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
</script>
```

Comment: can you show where '$_GET['lid']' is coming from and a _possible_ cause might because of whitespace at the end of lid.

Comment: i already edited the post and it show where the "$_GET['lid']" comes from

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: still unsure. can you do a `console.log(selectedTd);` and a `var_dump($loan, $loan1);` to see what is really being produced. Maybe the `$(this).find('td:first-child').text();` has extra content like whitespace or something else.

Comment: how do you do a console.log(selectedTd); and var_dump($loan, $loan1); am very new to this sorry

Comment: put `console.log` after the `find` part and put `var_dump` after creating $loan/loan1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the space or newline thing.

Please use `var_dump()` to check if `$loan` and `$loan1` are exactly the same:

```
var_dump($loan);
```

should out put

```
string(22) "201410000account-00002".
```

I guess you might get something like

```
string(23) "201410000account-00002 ".
```

Comment: i just echo mine its calling ' 201410000account-00002' in the $_GET['lid'] how can i make it '201410000account-00002' with out the extra space

Comment: You never know if there is a space or a new line with php `echo` . That's why I suggested to use `var_dump()` to find out if spaces are in your way. `$loan = trim($loan)` can remove spaces, tabs or new lines.

Comment: Please look at the <tr> and </tr>. The have to be balanced and in the loop there is missing </tr>.

Answer (score 0):

To trim the data change the following to trim `selectedTd`

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    selectedTd = $(this).find('td:first-child').text().trim();
});
```

or better yet do:

```
$loan = trim($_GET['lid']);
```